# Show that $P_k(x) = \frac {x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-k+1)}{k!}\forall k = 0,1,...,n$ determine a base in $\mathbb{R}_{\leq n}[X]$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Show that $P_k(x) = \frac {x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-k+1)}{k!}\forall k = 0,1,...,n$ determine a base in $\mathbb{R}_{\leq n}[X]$

I tried induction and tried to find all the coefficient for X but didn't work out.

$$P_0(x)= x+ 1$$
$$P_1(x)= x$$
$$P_2(x)= \frac {x^2-x}{2}$$
$$P_3(x) = \frac {x^3-3x^2+2x}{6}$$

and so on... but I can't find any general term to determine the coefficients are there any other ways?

Comment: Hint: prove by induction that $x^k$ is in ithe span of these polynomials for every $k=0,\dots,n.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acturally, $P_0(x)=1$. And it turns out that$$P_k(x)=\frac1{k!}x^k+\text{ terms of lower degree.}$$So, the coordinates of $P_k(x)$  in the basis $(x^n,x^{n-1},\ldots,1)$ are$$\biggl(\overbrace{0,\ldots,0}^{n-k\text{ times}},\frac1{k!},\ldots\biggr).$$If you write all these vectors as columns, then you'll get an upper triangular matrix such that the entries of the main diagonal are all different from $0$. Therefore, the $P_k(x)$'s are linearly independent. It follows that they form a basis.

Comment: Why the coordinates of $P_k(x)$ in the basis $(x^n, x^{n-1},...,1)$ are those?

Comment: Because$$P_k(x)=\frac1{k!}x^k+\text{ terms of lower degree.}$$

Answer (score 1):

There is an explicit formula to write $X^k$ as a linear combination of $P_0,P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_k$.  That is, we have
$$X^k=\sum_{r=0}^k \left\{\begin{array}{cc}k\\r\end{array}\right\}P_r(X),\tag{1}$$
where $\left\{\begin{array}{cc}k\\r\end{array}\right\}$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind):
$$\left\{\begin{array}{cc}k\\r\end{array}\right\}=\sum_{s=0}^r(-1)^s\binom{r}{s}(r-s)^k.$$  Because the monomials $X^k$ for $k=0,1,2\ldots,n$ form a basis of the vector space $\mathbb{R}_{\leq n}[X]$ of dimension $n+1$, it follows that $P_k(X)$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots,n$ also form a basis of this vector space (noting that a spanning set with the same number of elements as a basis must also be a basis).

To prove (1), we only have to verify that
$$t^k=\sum_{r=0}^ka(k,r)P_r(t)$$
for $t=0,1,2,\ldots,k$ (because two polynomials of degree at most $k$ must be equal if they agree at $k+1$ points).  In other words, we need to prove the equality 
$$t^k=\sum_{r=0}^k\binom{t}{r}\sum_{s=0}^r(-1)^s\binom{r}{s}(r-s)^k=\sum_{r=0}^t\binom{t}{r}\sum_{s=0}^r(-1)^s\binom{r}{s}(r-s)^k$$
for $t=0,1,2,\ldots,k$.  The RHS of the last equation is
$$RHS=\sum_{s=0}^t(-1)^s\sum_{r=s}^t\binom{t}{r}\binom{r}{s}(r-s)^k.$$
Since $\binom{t}{r}\binom{r}{s}=\binom{t}{s}\binom{t-r}{r-s}$, we have
$$RHS=\sum_{s=0}^t(-1)^s\binom{t}{s}\sum_{r=s}^t\binom{t-s}{r-s}(r-s)^k=\sum_{s=0}^t(-1)^s\binom{t}{s}\sum_{l=0}^{t-s}\binom{t-s}{l}l^k.$$
Hence,
$$RHS=\sum_{l=0}^tl^k\sum_{s=0}^{t-l}(-1)^s\binom{t-s}{l}\binom{t}{s}=\sum_{l=0}^tl^k\sum_{s=0}^{t-l}(-1)^s\binom{t-s}{l}\binom{t}{t-s}.$$
Again, we use $\binom{t}{t-s}\binom{t-s}{l}=\binom{t-l}{(t-s)-l}\binom{t}{l}=\binom{t-l}{(t-l)-s}\binom{t}{l}=\binom{t-l}{s}\binom{t}{l}$, so
$$RHS=\sum_{l=0}^t\binom{t}{l}l^k\sum_{s=0}^{t-l}(-1)^s\binom{t-l}{s}.$$
Because $\sum_{s=0}^{t-l}(-1)^s\binom{t-l}{s}=\delta_{t,l}$, we conclude that
$$RHS=\sum_{l=0}^t\binom{t}{l}l^k\delta_{t,l}=\binom{t}{t}t^k=t^k$$
for all $t=0,1,2,\ldots,k$.

---

But you can also do the other way around.  If you have a linearly independent set with the same number of elements as a basis, this linearly independent set must also be a basis.  Suppose that $P_0,P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_n$ are not linearly independent.  If $\sum_{j=0}^nb_jP_j(X)=0$ and $k$ is the largest index that $b_j\neq 0$, then
$$b_k=b_kP_k(k)=\sum_{j=0}^nb_jP_j(k)=0.$$
This is a contradiction.

You can also write $P_k(X)$ as a linear combination of $1,X,X^2,\ldots,X^k$.  That is,
$$P_k(X)=\sum_{r=0}^k(-1)^r\begin{bmatrix}k\\r\end{bmatrix} X^{k-r}.$$
Here, $\begin{bmatrix}k\\r\end{bmatrix}$ is the [Stirling number of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).